# Entity Framework Core cannot create Seed with Child objects and GUID's

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have the following entities:

```
 public class Artist
 {
     [Key]
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }

public class Song
{
    [Key] 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]  
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

For the `Song` class I'm trying to create a seed like for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Song>().HasData(new Song
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "test",
        Artist = new Artist
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "test"
        }
    });
```

This is throwing the following error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Song' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'ArtistId'.

I have no clue why I keep getting this error. When I try to seed the `Artist` object only, I have no issues. I also tried referencing an existing `Artist` object, however the result where the same.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the code can indeed run, however when trying to create a migration through the `Add-Migration InitialCreate` command, the error shows.

Comment: Your code runs without issue when I try it. Notice the error complains about `ArtistId` not being supplied. In your model, the key field is defined as `Id`.

Comment: You first insert record in the Artist table and then insert into Song table.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the code can indeed run, however when trying to create a migration through the `Add-Migration InitialCreate` command, the error shows. I will try to Change the property Id as mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution using an anonymous object (`new {}`). The problem was that my `Song` object didn't contain a `Guid ArtistId` property, but an `Artist Artist` property. However for some reason, EF migrations cannot relate with this object and required an id instead. With an anonymous object this could be fixed like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Song>().HasData(new //No Song object here.
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "test",
    ArtistId = artist.Id
});
```

and now I can run my migration.

**Update:**
I think the easier way to insert seed data now is to generate an empty migration and add your data through the `migrationBuilder.Sql()` method.

Comment: This approach is not correct, every time you create a migration a new Guid (and new data) seed data will be added to the migration.

Comment: This was not really an issue for me, so I think it's still valid.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, great!

Answer (score 0):

agree with @vivek nuna
First seed Artist and then seed Song, Please use ArtistId while seeding.

```
var artist = new Artist()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "test-a"
};

modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>().HasData(artist);
modelBuilder.Entity<Song>().HasData(new Song()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "test",
    ArtistId = artist.Id
});
```

I could add migrations using "Add-Migration" command.